# Sync iPod with iTunes

Tags: windows, itunes, mp3, ipod, podcasts

I recently bought a new computer. I installed iTunes on it and subscribed to all my favourite podcasts. When I plug in my iPod, iTunes tells me that an iPod can only be synced with a single iTunes library, so if I want to sync it with this iTunes library, I will lose all the data on the iPod.

All I really want to do is sync the podcasts on the iPod with the podcasts I've subscribed to in iTunes, but iTunes only seems to be offering me "all or nothing" syncing. Is there a way I can get iTunes to sync the podcasts, without erasing all the music? If iTunes erases all the music, I won't be able to import it again as the original mp3 files are on an external HD that I no longer have access to.

I don't mind using an alternative to iTunes as long as it supports podcast subscription and can run on Windows 7.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: I have used Amorak also but it is on Ubuntu.  [Here](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/07/08/10-alternatives-to-itunes-for-managing-your-ipod/) are a list of alternatives, some of which are Windows.  From my experience, I have found that Mediamonkey is the most complete.  Sharepod is not bad but the functionality is limited. As a consequence, I use Mediamonkey all the time.

Comment: BTW, I don't know of another approach. It is something that I have come across repeatedly and just changed my library manager instead.  I came across this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/5991/itunes-alternatives-to-manage-my-ipod), which outlines some further alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

As I hate iTunes (it is like an old bust-up tractor), I use [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/). You can find a guide to iPod syncing with it [here](http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/Guide_to_ipod_sync).

It works well but there may be issues with newer OS versions.

Comment: I'll give the monkey a try, thanks for the advice. I'll accept this answer if it works out